# Java EE RESTful service JSON marshalling 415 status with @Xml* annotations

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, jaxb

I have simple Java EE RESTful service, which used JAX-RS (Jersey), JPA (EclipseLink) and JAXB (EclipseLink MOXy) on Payara 4.1.1.154 (GlassFish 4.1.1 fork - http://payara.fish).

I use two entityes Radio and Stream with bidirectional link between them:

Radio entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Radio {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String genre;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @XmlIDREF
    private List<Stream> streams;

    @Version
    private long version;
    ... constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Streams entity

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Stream {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @XmlID
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String mountPoint;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Radio radio;

    @Version
    private long version;
    ... constructors, getters, setters
}
```

And RESTFul resource handler:

```
@Path("/radios")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RadioResource {

    @Inject
    private RadioService radioService;

    public RadioResource() {}

    @GET
    @Path("/{radioId}")
    public Radio getById(@PathParam("radioId") long id) throws com.roks.radio.rt.services.NotFoundException {
        return radioService.findById(id);
    }

    @POST
    public Response create(Radio radio, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws AlreadyExistsException {
        radioService.create(radio);
        return Response.created(
                uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(
                        String.valueOf(radio.getId())
                ).build()
        ).entity(radio).build();
    }
}
```

When doing POST request with type of application/json server responce with 415 status code (mediatype not supported). When I remove @XmlID and @XmlIDREF annotations from code, all working fine (201 Created responce), except missing "streams" field in JSON output.

I think "streams" not present because of circular reference in result JSON object when streams list empty. But I try to remove this reference with @XmlID and @XmlREFID annotations, but JSON marshalling stop working.

In JSON output i mainly need "streams" field with streams IDs.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you looked at `@XmlValue` annotation for the stream id? Maybe that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

try to use the annotation

```
@JsonProperty
```

on the getters you want to be marshalled in json (org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty).

Are you using jersey-media-moxy.jar in your project? It's purpose is to bind objects to JSON. I used it once but i'm not sure i still have the source.

Comment: I found that the \@JsonProperty annotation used with Jackson, but I use EclipseLink MOXy, and what to do with circular link between entities when I remove \@Xml annotations?

Comment: it's true, i will edit my answer as you need the annotations:

Comment: can you post the answer you get when removing the xml annotations?

Comment: Without XmlID and XmlIDREF annotations i have 201 Created status with body: {"id":2,"name":"radio 2","genre":"rock,"version":1}. JSON marshalling stop working when I add this annotations.

Comment: The same result, when I do POST I have 415 Status. Without XmlID and XmlIDREF, rsult as in my previous reply.

Comment: can you paste the body of your post?

Comment: {"name":"radio 2", "genre": "rock"}

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the answer you get then. The Radio object that you post has an empty list of Streams.

Comment: 1. Empty list of streams absent, it must be like "streams":[]
2. Annotations disable JSON marshalling.

Comment: if you write 
radio = radioService.create(radio);
instead of
radioService.create(radio);

Comment: my last comment is because the 'radio' object that you return is not the returned object from the 'create'.
What is your result when you create a Radio containing a non empty List of Stream?